# Threaded Sql Query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multithreading

ive searched for the archive but cant find a suitable entry. sorry if exists.

im using vs2008, .NET 3.5, MS-SQL2008

My Code is simple;

```
SqlConnection CONN=new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString);
CONN.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = CONN.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText="SELECT FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3 from table1";

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

so DataTable dt is ready to use.

But i want to make the query stoppable by user, coz it may last too much long to wait. so user will stop the query, change parameters and requery.

Also i want to show a stopwatch for query time, during query execution.

As expected, i cant do those in the same thread of sql query.

What should be the best and simplest threading approach for above code? can someone reply a piece of code for that? note that; DataTable dt must be available for the main thread at the end.

thanks in advance

Comment: @SATSON using a different thread won't stop the query on the remote server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you want to do a separate thread and execute the command there you can try this code:

```
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(LoadDB));
thread.Start();
//put this command wherever you want

private void LoadDB()
{
SqlConnection CONN=new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString);
CONN.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = CONN.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText="SELECT FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3 from table1";

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is not asynchronous or cancellable API for `IDbDataAdapter` or `DataTable.Load`, so your only way is to do the job in a ThreadPool thread like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108944/307976 and forget about it if you want to cancel it.

Comment: Cancelling a server command is not related to the client thread

Comment: wat about using SqlCommand.Cancel? Do SqlCommand.Cancel stop the query on remote side? i think that can be done someway. User can stop the query in Management studio and Toad For SqlServer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader` to start an asynchronous command. This allows you to handle UI (your "stopwatch"), and continue work in the asynchronous callback.

Going back to a UI thread is simple, if the callback doesn't end up back there automatically, just use `Invoke` on some control and that code will be processed on the UI thread at the earliest convenience.

You can call `SqlCommand.Cancel` to try and cancel the query, which should work, mostly. If it doesn't, your only other choice is to create another `SqlConnection` and another `SqlCommand`, and kill the *other* connection through SQL.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlCommand.Cancel` might be of use here.

Create a class as given in the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). This link gives a good example of how to start a thread and terminate it gracefully.

The class `Worker` in this link has 2 methods which you should take note of. `DoWork` within which you can call your sql query and the other is `RequestStop` within which you can call your `SqlCommand.Cancel` which should stop your execution of the query on server side. `RequestStop` method can be called by a user event like button click which in turn will stop execution of query.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
    Thread t = new Thread(() => {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_someConnectionString)) {

            string query = "SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM table1";

                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con)) {

                    try {

                       con.Open();

                       using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader()) {
                           if (reader.HasRows) {
                               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                               dt.Load(reader);
                           }

                       }

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        // Anything you want to do with ex
                    } finally {
                        con.Close();
                    }

                }

        }

    });

    t.IsBackground = true;

    t.Start();
```